# qt 5.0.1 mingw 32bit issue

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I've installed Qt 5.0.1 mingw SDK. but there's an issue in the compilation of c++ project.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've the following compilation error: `..testmain.cpp: No such file or directory`
This is the pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

For now the solution is to modify the Makefile.Debug and change this line:

```
debug/main.o: ../test/main.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o debug\main.o ..\test\main.cpp
```

with:

```
debug/main.o: ../test/main.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o debug/main.o ../test/main.cpp
```

But this isn't a good way, because for any rebuild I've to change the makefile and for large projects this is unacceptable.

Do someoune know what I'm wrong?

Comment: Are you running this under msys? Try running from a non-msys shell

Comment: no, i'm using qt creator without msys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The issue is with my TortoiseGit. TortoiseGit has a MSYS integrated and this clash with qt creator. I'll report the bug to the qt-project

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it might be a bug in [qmake](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29561)